# Kafka consumer group offset retention

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

How long does kafka store the offset of a consumer-group after all consumers in that group fail?
Is there a configuration variable for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The right property name is:

```
offsets.retention.minutes
```

from https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs

Comment: offsets.retention.minutes is at broker level. Is there anything at topic level?

Comment: This is a read-only broker config.  Can we change this by any kafka cli command, Instead of server.properties. ?

Answer (score 8):

The value can be configured in **kafka broker** using:

```
offsets.retention.minutes
```

The default is `24` hours.

**See:** the Kafka broker config [docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs).

Comment: offsets.retention.minutes is at broker level. Is there anything at topic level?

Comment: The default has been made more sane in 2.0.0 - it defaults to 7 days.

Answer (score 2):

I have added following property in Kafka configuration,
it changed the offset retention time to 7 days, and working good.

**offsets.retention.minutes=10080**[image]